# Self-adjoint operator and vertex conditions in quantum graphs

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, boundary-value-problem

Let $\Gamma$ be a metric graph with finitely many edges. Consider the operator $H$ acting as $\frac{-d^2}{dx_e^2}$ on each edge $e$, with the domain consisting of functions that belong to $H^2(e)$ on each edge $e$ and satisfy the boundary condition $A_vF + B_vF' = 0$ at each vertex. Here $\{A_v, B_v :v \in V\}$ is a collection of matrices of sizes $d_v \times d_v$ (Here $d_v$ is the number of edges that are connected to $v$) such that each matrix $(A_v \; B_v)$ has the maximal rank. In order for $H$ to be self-adjoint, the following condition at each vertex is necessary and sufficient:

$\textrm{the matrix }A_vB_v^*\textrm{ is self-adjoint.}$

This is a theorem from: *P. Kuchment. Quantum Graphs I. Some Basic Structures. Texas A&M University*.

He says that proof can be found in *V. Kostrykin and R. Schrader. Kirchhoff's rule in quantum wires* but does someone know more direct proof? In the second paper they use maximal isotropic subspaces but I would like not to use that.

Thank you very much.